# Finding the sum of an infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Question:

> If $$x = \frac{7}{4\times 1\times 2} + \frac{10}{4^2\times 2\times 3} + \frac{13}{4^3\times 3\times 4} +\dots $$
> then find the value of $x$.

I managed to find the $n^\text{th}$ term as

> $$t_n = \frac{\frac{4}{n} - \frac{1}{1+n}}{4^n}$$

I also tried to find some arithmetic or geometric series hidden in the question, but $1\times 2$, $2\times 3$,... in the denominator were quite problematic for me to deal with.

Please provide a solution which does not make use of calculus as I haven't taken it yet. Thank you.

Comment: @DonAntonio It is not that odd as long as it is not intended for standard homework/control work. Maybe some sort of olympiad or stuff...

Comment: @VIVID Apparently so. Where I studied, and it was a good academic level, we didn't cover infinite series except for geometric ones. Telescopic series was for rather advanced students who, perhaps, were already seeing some university mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:your general term is $$\frac{4+3r}{4^r(r)(r+1)}=\frac{1}{4^{r-1}r}-\frac{1}{4^r(r+1)}$$

Now telescope.....

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One classically has
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}=-\ln(1-x),\quad |x|<1,
$$$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n+1}=-1-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x},\quad |x|<1.
$$

Comment: This uses quite a lot of calculus: power/Taylor series of functions...

Comment: Sure: just another interesting point of view...

Comment: Diversity, is a key....